# Conditional formatting(background cell) multiple columns using reactable lib

Tags: r

I've a dataframe with 30 columns. But from 4 to 30th columns I have to apply a condition. If the value is equal to 1 or more then the background cell change to Red(lightCoral). I did it,  For the moment I apply the change on all the columns concerned and it works. It makes a lot of codes. I need a good way to simplify my codes.

```
ds_color=NULL
reactable(tab_jan2021, filterable = TRUE, minRows = 100,defaultPageSize = 100,columns = list(
  SORTIE= colDef(cell = function(value) {
    # Render as an X mark or check mark
    if (value == 0) "\u274c No" else "\u2714\ufe0f Yes"
  }),
  ID = colDef(
       style = list(position = "sticky", left = 0, background = "#fff", zIndex = 1),
       headerStyle = list(position = "sticky", left = 0, background = "#fff", zIndex = 1)
    ),
  FAIBLESSE = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      ds_color <- "lightCoral"
    } 
    list(background = ds_color)
  }
  ),
  FATIGUE = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      ds_color <- "lightCoral"
    } 
    list(background = ds_color)
  }
  ),
  MAUX_DE_TETE = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      ds_color <- "lightCoral"
    } 
    list(background = ds_color)
  }
  ),
  ANOREXIE = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      ds_color <- "lightCoral"
    } 
    list(background = ds_color)
  }
  ),
  MAL_DE_GORGE = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      ds_color <- "lightCoral"
    } 
    list(background = ds_color)
  }
  ),
  NAUSEE = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      ds_color <- "lightCoral"
    } 
    list(background = ds_color)
  }
  ),
  DOUL_THORA = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      ds_color <- "lightCoral"
    } 
    list(background = ds_color)
  }
  ),
  DIFF_RESPI = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      ds_color <- "lightCoral"
    } 
    list(background = ds_color)
  }
  ),
  DIFF_A_AVALER = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      ds_color <- "lightCoral"
    } 
    list(background = ds_color)
  }
  ),
  DOUL_ABDO = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      ds_color <- "lightCoral"
    } 
    list(background = ds_color)
  }
  ),
  DIARRHEE = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      ds_color <- "lightCoral"
    } 
    list(background = ds_color)
  }
  ),
  VOMISSEMENT = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      ds_color <- "lightCoral"
    } 
    list(background = ds_color)
  }
  ),
  TROUBLE_DE_SOMMEIL = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      ds_color <- "lightCoral"
    } 
    list(background = ds_color)
  }
  ),
  ENGOURDISSEMENT = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      ds_color <- "lightCoral"
    } 
    list(background = ds_color)
  }
  ),
  SUEUR_FROIDE = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      ds_color <- "lightCoral"
    } 
    list(background = ds_color)
  }
  ),
  STRESS = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      ds_color <- "lightCoral"
    } 
    list(background = ds_color)
  }
  ),
  PERTE_EQUILIBRE = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      ds_color <- "lightCoral"
    } 
    list(background = ds_color)
  }
  ),
  OSTEO_ARTICULAIRE = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      ds_color <- "lightCoral"
    } 
    list(background = ds_color)
  }
  ),
  DOUL_MUSCULAIRE = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      ds_color <- "lightCoral"
    } 
    list(background = ds_color)
  }
  )
),defaultColDef = colDef(minWidth = 155),resizable = TRUE,wrap = FALSE,)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's use an example data set everyone has. Then we can apply special formatting e.g. on all length columns:

```r
library(reactable)
library(tidyverse)

columns <-
  iris %>%
  colnames() %>%
  set_names() %>%
  # filter the columns you want to apply special formatting
  # Here: column 4 to 4
  keep(~ .x %in% colnames(iris)[2:4]) %>%
  map(~ {
    colDef(
      style = function(value) {
        ds_color <- ifelse(value > 1.6, "lightCoral", "green")
        list(background = ds_color)
      }
    )
  })

reactable(iris, columns = columns)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi, Did you try your own codes? It gives an error.  "Error in set_names(.) : 1 argument passed to 'names<-' which requires 2"

Comment: Yes, this is a reproducible example using tidyverse version 1.3.1

Comment: I just retested your code works, but I can't adapt it to my situation. If you know how to adapt it, it will be easy for me.

Comment: You asked for how to write concice code to set the background color of a cell in particular columns based on its value. That's what my answer is about. The only thing you need to do is to change the conditions in `keep` and `ifelse` according to your needs. `iris` is the data frame. I changed my answer to select columns based on their positions

Comment: How would you add additional formatting for a single column? E.g. Bolding Petal.Length. Also, why do you use `{` after `map( ~`?